# In SQL Server, can user X be granted ability to change permissions for all users except Y?

Tags: sql-server

...and if so, how?  Sorry for such a newbie question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can grant the permission with the ability to grant to others but you would have to put something else in place to restrict that user from granting it to a specific user. It is grantable or not.

Answer (score 0):

For most typical implementations of SQL Server (e.g. all objects are stored within the `dbo` schema), I cannot think of a permission set that will allow you to do this without the inclusion of some DDL trigger that prevents certain operations against a user, just as @dbaduck alludes to.

While `DENY` permissions are always prioritized over `GRANT` permissions ([ref](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2894/understanding-grant-deny-and-revoke-in-sql-server/)), this scenario is a bit of a paradox because the moment you grant a user the ability to control permissions on schema objects is the same moment that user can now `REVOKE` any restrictions you would have imposed upon him/her as is related to said schema objects.  Convoluted, right?  If you love confusing graphs, I'm going to point you to MS's [Permissions (Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine) article.  Within it, you'll see the way that permission inheritance is laid out.  What this shed's light on is that permissions on a user are not the same as permissions on the a schema, and because of this there's really no clean way of doing what you want without some DDL trigger tomfoolery.

Comment: I'd been looking at that poster of permissions, but I understood it to be for the fixed roles.  I was hoping that a user-defined role could be made that has the db_owner permissions, and then DENY from that role the ability to mess with my user or my user being the db_owner (like DENY CONTROL ON USER::MyUser TO AlmostDbOwnerRole), and then add that user to that new role with grant.